MS Access Joining Tables After totaling
I have tables A, B, C, and D.
They all have the following fields:
Division, Vendor, Deal, Reference, and Amount.
I want my final table to contain Division, Vendor, Deal, Reference, and 4 separate Amount columns from each table (Amount A, Amount B, Amount C, Amount D).
Before joining these tables I need to total the amounts based on the other fields because they are not unique until they are totaled.
The join should keep information from all tables regardless if it finds a match in the other tables.
How do I go about doing this in MS Access?

Create and save a union query to build the complete list of entries:
Select Division, Vendor, Deal, Reference
From TableA
Union
Select Division, Vendor, Deal, Reference
From TableB
Union
Select Division, Vendor, Deal, Reference
From TableC
Union
Select Division, Vendor, Deal, Reference
From TableD

Now, use this query as source in a new select query where you use Left Join to  join each of the four tables to the union query.
Select the four fields from the union query and the four amount fields from the tables to return these fields:
Division, Vendor, Deal, Reference, AmountA, AmountB, AmountC, AmountD

Save this query.
Finally, use this query as source in yet a query where you do your math as you like.

This is the right approach for MS-Access.  I think I would include the various Amounts right in the Union query so I did not reference the base tables a second time.  Like this: Select  Division,... Reference, Amount as AmountA, 0 as AmountB, 0 as AmountC, 0 as AmountD  from TableA UNION Select ..., 0 as AmountA, Amount as AmountB, 0 as AmountD  etc.  That way the second query becomes a simple sum of the first query's results.

I don't know if you can do it in MS Access, but it almost sounds like a CTE would work the best for you. You could have had with TableA(a,b,c,d,dollarAmt)(do math), etc. Then, at the end, you would have your final query that works in everything and only brings in the columns you want by doing a left outer join. then you would have select vendor,tableAsum,TableBSum etc.
I just don't know if you can do that in MS Access but that's what it sounds like it would solve your issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
